# Nutch - How to split html page into multiple pages with own url?

Tags: parsing, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I have a page (http://www.example.com/content), which contains multiple blocks

```
 <div>
 <h1 id="titleOne">First title</h1>
 Here is custom content
 <h1 id="titleTwo">Second title</h1>
 Here is custom content for part 2
 </div>
```

I want to index this page like 2 separate pages which differ in url and contains on text from <h1> to another <h1> element.

Example:

Document 1: http://www.example.com/content#titleOne

Document 2: http://www.example.com/content#titleTwo